# En dehors de l'etudie / sous mon professeur ?

Tags: prépositions, verbes

> Bonjour, je m'appelle montserrat martinez et j'ai 18 ans. J'ai etudie
>   le francais pour quatre ans en Ganesha High School **sous mon professeur**
>   madame Siu. **En dehors de l'etudie**, Je aime apprendre de la culture, la
>   musique et les médias francais. Certains de mes celbrities prefere
>   sont Stromae, Jena Lee et Youtuber, Cyprien.

I am unsure of a few parts of the paragraph:

1. *En dehors de l'etudie*: I am trying to say "Apart from just studying" but it sounds a bit off. I think this sounds strange
   because usually, it think it would be "aussi" but it does not show
   what I am trying to say if i just use "aussi" instead of the
   word/expression for "apart"
2. *sous mon professeur madame Siu*: I am trying to say "under my teacher madame sui." but this sounds a bit strange, I have never
   attempted to write this sentence before so I am a bit unsure.

Comment: This text must reflect your French skill, there are translation mistakes, but we understand what you mean, and see that you are able to be understood in French. If we make it perfect, it would reflect your actual skill. If you want a better translation, you would need more practice, or you could "feel" where there may have mistakes, and ask a question about "why does **this part** sound wrong ?" for instance and explain why you think it's wrong, we would explain your mistake with pleasure :)

Comment: Installez LibreOffice en français sur votre ordinateur, puis l'utilitaire grammalecte : quand vous taperez un texte, les fautes d'orthographe, d'accents, d'accord seront soulignées. N.B. : Nom et Prénom prennent une majuscule, l'étude (sans le *i*). *Je +* mot commençant par une voyelle --> *j'* ; on étudie pas *sous*, mais *avec* ; Transposition : Je m'intéresse aussi à la culture,...

Comment: Reopened, but one question per post would be even better.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Thank you, I completely agree. I'm pretty certain that as the question is allowed, the user will remember this and fully comply the next time they ask a question. Thanks again!

Comment: Thank you all so much for reopening this, I will keep all of this in mind next time I make a post :)

Answer (score 2):

*Sous* is indeed odd here. If you want to keep it, that would be *sous l'égide de mon professeur*. A more usual expression is *avec comme professeur Madame Siu*.

*En dehors de l'etudie* is hard to read due to a missing accent and a grammatical error. I guess you want to write *En dehors de l'étudier* but this is partially contradictory given the fact learning the culture, listening to music and reading the media is still *étudier*. You might want to say: *En plus des cours de français, ...*

There are also a dozen of typos and mistakes in the remaining of your paragraph. I would advise you to use the suggestions already posted as comments to improve it.